# Sitecore SXA - Multi-Root TreeList - Data Source Query

Tags: templates, sitecore, sitecore-sxa

Within our Sitecore SXA 1.9 project, we're having a Template with a Multi-Root Treelist field.

This field has the following query:

```
query:/sitecore/content/Event Sites//*[@@name='Home']
```

As a result, the field is populated as:

[image: Multi-Root Treelist populated by query]

Would it be possible to display the actual website names instead of '**(Current Site)**'?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this code (https://gist.github.com/kamsar/33d1245ffdb630b1f126) for multi root treelist, then you should be able by creating a custom MultiRootTreeView by extending MultiRootTreeView and use it instead of the default *Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.MultiRootTreeview()*

Create a custom tree view here (adjust according to your need btw)

```
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.FieldTypes
{
    public class EnhancedMultiRootTreeview : MultiRootTreeview
    {
        protected override string GetHeaderValue(Item item)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");

            var nodeTitle = string.IsNullOrEmpty(DisplayFieldName) ? item.DisplayName : item[DisplayFieldName];

            return $"{nodeTitle}  -  <span>({item.Paths.ContentPath})</span>";
        }
    }
}
```

Use your Custom MultiRootTreeview here (within your MultiRootTreeList Implementation)

```
var impostor = new EnhancedMultiRootTreeview
{
   ID = existingTreeView.ID,
   DblClick = existingTreeView.DblClick,
   Enabled = existingTreeView.Enabled,
   DisplayFieldName = existingTreeView.DisplayFieldName
};
```